# Access item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

If I have a list of lists and just want to manipulate an individual item in that list, how would I go about doing that?

For example:

```
List1 = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]
```

What if I want to take a value (say 50) and look just at the first sublist in `List1`, and subtract 10 (the first value), then add 13, then subtract 17?

Answer (score 71):

You can access the elements in a list-of-lists by first specifying which list you're interested in and then specifying which element of that list you want. For example, `17` is element `2` in list `0`, which is `list1[0][2]`:

```
>>> list1 = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]
>>> list1[0][2]
17
```

So, your example would be

```
50 - list1[0][0] + list1[0][1] - list1[0][2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.cycle`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> lis = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]
>>> cyc = cycle((-1, 1))
>>> 50 + sum(x*next(cyc) for x in lis[0])   # lis[0] is [10,13,17]
36
```

Here the generator expression inside `sum` would return something like this:

```
>>> cyc = cycle((-1, 1))
>>> [x*next(cyc) for x in lis[0]]
[-10, 13, -17]
```

You can also use `zip` here:

```
>>> cyc = cycle((-1, 1))
>>> [x*y for x, y  in zip(lis[0], cyc)]
[-10, 13, -17]
```

Comment: `itertools` has so many gems. Thanks, didn't know about `cycle`.

Comment: @DonaldMiner Thanks to Raymond Hettinger for creating this awesome module. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This code will print each individual number:

```
for myList in [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]:
    for item in myList:
        print(item)
```

Or for your specific use case:

```
((50 - List1[0][0]) + List1[0][1]) - List1[0][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List1 = [[10,-13,17],[3,5,1],[13,11,12]]

num = 50
for i in List1[0]:num -= i
print num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
50 - List1[0][0] + List[0][1] - List[0][2]
```

`List[0]` gives you the first list in the list (try out `print List[0]`). Then, you index into it again to get the items of that list. Think of it this way: `(List1[0])[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in list1:
    val = 50 - l[0] + l[1] - l[2]
    print "val:", val
```

Loop through list and do operation on the sublist as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = list(zip(*old_list)))
```

*old_list unpacks old_list into multiple lists and zip picks corresponding nth element from each list and list packs them back.

Answer (score 0):

```
to print every individual element in double list
        list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            for j in range(len(list1[i])):
                print(list1[i][j])
```