# How to export Mysql Table data to excel file using python script?

Tags: python-2.7

I have been trying to export that data from table to excel file using python 2.7.8 but I have not succeeded. Please help me. My Requirement is to export the data from the table and store it in local(windows C Drive).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import base64
import os
import sys
import xlswriter
import xlwt
import datetime
import MySQLdb
from pyh import *
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.1.118","stp","stp","STP")
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ("""select * from stp_automation_output""")
cursor.execute(query)
myresults = cursor.fetchall()
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("My Sheet")
#date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd mmmm yyyy'})
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
worksheet.write('A1','Sno',bold)
worksheet.write('B1','function_name',bold)
worksheet.write('C1','input1',bold)
worksheet.write('D1','input2',bold)
worksheet.write('E1','input3',bold)
worksheet.write('F1','Expected_output',bold)
worksheet.write('G1','Actual_output',bold)
worksheet.write('H1','Result',bold)
row = 1
col = 0
for Sno,function_name,input1,input2,input3,Expected_output,Actual_output,Result in (myresults):
  Sno = row[0]
  function_name = row[1]
  input1 = row[2]
  input2 = row[3]
  input3 = row[4]
  Expected_output = row[5]
  Actual_output = row[6]
  Result = row[7]
workbook.save()
```

Answer (score 9):

This is probably something you can do more easily *without* using Python, but here's a skeleton structure. Note this writes to a .csv, not an Excel file. You can use the `xlwt` library to accomplish the latter.

Note you'll need to `pip install MySQL-python` first, which is usually painless but [occasionally not painless](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2012/11/is-mysqldb-hard-to-install.html).

```
import MySQLdb
import csv

user = '' # your username
passwd = '' # your password
host = '' # your host
db = '' # database where your table is stored
table = '' # table you want to save

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
cursor.execute(query)

with open('outfile','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**EDIT** — This should write it to Excel, but I'm not very familiar with `xlwt` and I haven't tested this code.

```
import MySQLdb
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

user = '' # your username
passwd = '' # your password
host = '' # your host
db = '' # database where your table is stored
table = '' # table you want to save

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
cursor.execute(query)

workbook = Workbook('outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me but my requirement is to export the table data to Excel file for which i have written code. Please help me.

Comment: I've tried. If it helped, please upvote and/or select my answer.

Comment: @jgysland : I tried your code, and I couldn't see any file exported. :( Do you know why ?

Comment: @ihue: you can't find the file? Did you look in the same directory from which the script was executed?

Comment: Make sure to close the workbook other wise it might not save it. "workbook.close()" at the end. Adding this allowed it to save it for me :)

Comment: I tried the above example and it creates xls and always the first record it writes. Why it does not write all the records from the DB table? i.e loop is not working

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this:

```
import mysql.connector
from openpyxl import Workbook

def main():

    # Connect to DB -----------------------------------------------------------
    db = mysql.connector.connect( user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1')
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Create table ------------------------------------------------------------
    database = 'test_database'
    SQL = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + database + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()

    SQL = 'USE ' + database + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)

    # Create car data ---------------------------------------------------------
    cars_table_name = 'cars'
    SQL = (
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + cars_table_name +
        '('
        '    model_year YEAR, '
        '    manufacturer VARCHAR(40), '
        '    product VARCHAR(40)'
        ');')
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()

    # Python list of dictionaries
    # More info at:
    #     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search
    car_data = [
      { 'model_year': '2010', 'manufacturer': 'Toyota', 'product': 'Prius' },
      { 'model_year': '2010', 'manufacturer': 'Honda', 'product': 'CR-V' },
      { 'model_year': '1998', 'manufacturer': 'Honda', 'product': 'Civic' },
      { 'model_year': '1997', 'manufacturer': 'Ford', 'product': 'F-150' },
      { 'model_year': '2017', 'manufacturer': 'Tesla', 'product': 'Model 3' },
    ]

    # Code adapted from: 
    #     https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html
    add_cars = ('INSERT INTO ' + cars_table_name + ' (model_year, manufacturer, product) '
                '    VALUES (%(model_year)s, %(manufacturer)s, %(product)s)')

    for car_datum in car_data:
        cur.execute(add_cars, car_datum);
    db.commit()

    # Create manufacturer data -----------------------------------------------
    manufacturer_table_name = 'manufacturer'
    SQL = (
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + manufacturer_table_name +
        '('
        '    name VARCHAR(40), '
        '    headquarters VARCHAR(40), '
        '    number_of_employees INT, '
        '    website VARCHAR(40)'
        ');')
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()

    add_manufacturer = (
        'INSERT INTO ' + manufacturer_table_name + 
        ' (name, headquarters, number_of_employees, website) '
        '    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)')

    # Python list of lists
    # More info at:
    #     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists
    # Data from:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyota
    # Honda data from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda
    # Ford data from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford
    # Tesla data from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla,_Inc.
    manufacture_data = [
      [ 'Toyota', 'Toyota, Aichi, Japan', '364445', 'http://toyota-global.com/' ],
      [ 'Honda', 'Minato, Tokyo, Japan', '208399', 'http://world.honda.com/' ],
      [ 'Ford', 'Dearborn, Michigan, U.S.', '201000', 'http://www.ford.com/' ],
      [ 'Tesla, Inc.', 'Palo Alto, California, US', '33000', 'http://www.tesla.com/' ],
    ]

    for manufacturer_datum in manufacture_data:
        cur.execute(add_manufacturer, manufacturer_datum);
    db.commit()

    # Create Excel (.xlsx) file -----------------------------------------------
    wb = Workbook()

    SQL = 'SELECT * from '+ cars_table_name + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
    ws.title = cars_table_name
    ws.append(cur.column_names)
    for row in results:
        ws.append(row)

    SQL = 'SELECT * from '+ manufacturer_table_name + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    ws = wb.create_sheet(0)
    ws.title = manufacturer_table_name
    ws.append(cur.column_names)
    for row in results:
        ws.append(row)

    workbook_name = "test_workbook"
    wb.save(workbook_name + ".xlsx")

    # Remove tables and database ----------------------------------------------
    SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + manufacturer_table_name + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()
    SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + cars_table_name + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()
    SQL = 'DROP DATABASE ' + database + ';'
    cur.execute(SQL)
    db.commit()

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```