# How to access values of list inside list- Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a game using pygame but I'm having problems with lists inside other lists.

inside the class of Enemy/Enemy 2 i have the following code:

```
ei = [[Enemy(), Enemy()][Enemy2()]]

for wave in ei:
    if self in wave:
        print(ei.index(self))
```

The object is inside the list, I have checked by printing out `ei` in bulk, however this code just returns 'None'.

I tried to `print('True')` instead of the index, however it still prints `None`

Comment: Please ensure the code you provided is properly formatted using the syntax highlighting tools, and ensure the indentation here is exactly as the code you have in your own editor.

Comment: You may [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. We don't know what `self` is in the context you've given

Comment: Is Enemy and Enemy2 the same class or different classes? Where in the class is this code? In `\_\_init\_\_()`? Is it even in a method? Provide the necessary information and your question will be easier to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access item in a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: You missed a comma there? I assume that you want two `waves` (whatever those are) and the first one has two `Enemy` and the second one has a `Enemy2`. The biggest problem is, `self` won't be in `ei`, it would be in `wave`. If you want the index of the wave which contains `self` (not sure, just guessing) then... see my answer. But I am guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, and there are several problems in your example. But maaaybe you want this:

```
for index, wave in enumerate(ei):
    if self in wave:
        print(index)
```

See my comments or elaborate your question --as already recommended by other users, provide a MCVE and fix/explain the variables and classes.