# Python: How do I replace value in a nested list?

Tags: python

How do I replace James's salary from 1000 to 1500 and print James's data?

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
           ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
           ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

for (name,appt,salary) in data:
    if name == 'James':
        salary = 1500
        print(linked_data[1])
```

Here's my current output:

```
['James', 'Cleaner', 1000]
```

Expected output:

```
['James', 'Cleaner', 1500]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unpacking from the list in for loop and creating 3 variables `name`, `appt` and `salary`. With this variables it isn't possible to easily change your  `data` structure. What you need is extract a list from `data` and access it by indexing:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
           ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
           ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

for d in data:
    if d[0] == 'James':
        d[2] = 1500
        print(d)  # prints only changed row

pprint(data)  # prints whole structure
```

Prints:

```
['James', 'Cleaner', 1500]
[['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
 ['James', 'Cleaner', 1500],
 ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to find the index at which it occurs. Use `enumerate`.

```
for idx, (name,appt,salary) in enumerate(data):
    if name == 'James':
        # salary is at index 2 in the inner list
        data[idx][2] = 1500
        print(f"{name},{appt},{salary}")
```

Comment: that tuple unpacking, solid stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the index then you can do:

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
           ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
           ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]


data[1][2] = 1500

print(data[1])
```

output:

```
['James', 'Cleaner', 1500]
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're trying to iterate over three values that don't actually make sense as parameters to the `for` loop. What you need to do is access one nested array at a time, check if that array's name is James, and if it is, you change the salary.

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
        ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
        ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

for (person) in data:
    if person[0] == 'James':
        # change index 1 (occupation) to 1500
        person[1] = 1500

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
 ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
 ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **access the second sublist** of the list and then the **third element** of the sublist to change it. Have a look at the code below:

```
data[1][2] = 1500
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using a dictionary to store your information, like this:

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
        ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
        ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

data_dict = {k: {'position': p, 'salary': s} for k, p, s in data}

data_dict['James']['salary'] = 1500

print(data_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Ben': {'position': 'Manager', 'salary': 3000}, 'James': {'position': 'Cleaner', 'salary': 1500}, 'Ken': {'position': 'Supervisor', 'salary': 2000}}
```

If you need to convert it back to a list, just use this:

```
print([[k] + list(v.values()) for k, v in data_dict.items()])
```

Output:

```
[['Ben', 'Manager', 3000], ['James', 'Cleaner', 1500], ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the salary:

```
data[1][2] = 1500
```

To print the data:

```
print(data[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `salary` is just a copy of the value from `data`. You should modify the original list instead of the copy. The function `enumerate` can generate the index (from 0) you need for changing the value inside the list.

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000],
       ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000],
       ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

for i, (name, appt, salary) in enumerate(data):
    if name == 'James':
        data[i][2] = 1500
        print(data[i])
```

The output: ['James', 'Cleaner', 1500]

Answer (score 0):

I think using class to replace 2D list is better to do.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, job, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.salary = salary

    def __str__(self):

        return '[{}, {}, {}]'.format(self.name, self.job, self.salary)

    def __repr__(self):

        return '[{}, {}, {}]'.format(self.name, self.job, self.salary)

data = [Employee('James', 'Cleaner', 1000),
        Employee('Ben', 'Manager', 3000)]

print(data)

for employee in data:
   if employee.name == 'James':
    employee.salary = 1500
    print(employee)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[James, Cleaner, 1000], [Ben, Manager, 3000]]
[James, Cleaner, 1500]
[[James, Cleaner, 1500], [Ben, Manager, 3000]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also Use This

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000], ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000], ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
change = 3000
name = 'Ben'
print([[x, y, change] if x == name else [x, y, z] for x, y, z in data])
```

So You get this Output:
[['Ben', 'Manager', 3000], ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000], ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]

Answer (score 0):

If You Want To Use Simple For Loop Then

```
data = [['Ben', 'Manager', 3000], ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000], ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
for x in data:
    if 'Ben' in x:
        x[-1] = 1500
print(data) 
#Output: [['Ben', 'Manager', 1500], ['James', 'Cleaner', 1000], ['Ken', 'Supervisor', 2000]]
```