# Writing an arrays inside an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I need to create empty arrays inside an array in order to fill each one of them differently in a loop later on but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax. I tried something like this:

```
 verilerimiz = [arrayname1[], arrayname2[], arrayname3[], arrayname4[], arrayname5[]]
```

Bu it gives a syntax error. I really appreciate some help.

Comment: have you tried using `numpy.empty ` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

Comment: Just remove the names: `verilerimiz = [[], [], [], ...]`

Comment: You probably want to read about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): `v = {'a1': [], 'a2': [], 'a3': []}`, so you can access e.g. `a2` by name: `v['a2'].append(123)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is an object in Python. And Lists can accept any type of data. So List can accept Lists too. Using this you can just place lists in a list.

```
array1 = [] # main array

array2 = [] 
array3 = []
array4 = []

array1 = [array2, array3, array4] # Or you can just give [] instead of variable names
```

## This will create the following

```
array1
[[], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you (if i understand your question correctly):

```
verilerimiz = list()
for i in range(5):
    verilerimiz.append(list())

# adding 'some value' to `arrayname1`
verilerimiz[0].append("some value")
```

Comment: youre welcome @AslıhanYılmaz

Comment: there was a syntax error in `for` loop indentation. i fixed it and now it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> here's my example

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = [1,2,3]

fa = [a1,a2,a3]
print(len(fa[2]))
```

also, check this out for referencing:
[Access item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists)