# How can i access list values in a dictionary

Tags: python

How could I get this working?

```
color_table = {"Red":[1,2,3], "Blue":[4,5,6]}
```

How can I access values individually?

```
color_table[Red].0 = 1
color_table[Red].1 = 2
color_table[Red].2 = 3
color_table[Blue].0 = 4
color_table[Blue].1 = 5
```

I want to assign these values to a variable.
For ex:

```
x = color_table[Red].0
```

Comment: Replace `.x` with `[x]`, and add quotes around the keys: for example `color_table[Red].0` should be `color_table["Red"][0]`, `color_table[Red].1` should be `color_table["Red"][1]`, and so forth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: (Regarding the duplicate: list of lists, dict of lists: doesn't matter)

Answer (score 6):

You're close. 
Make sure you refer to keys like "Red" and "Blue" by surrounding them with quotes in the key reference. Like so: `color_table["Red"]`

This will return the value for that key in the dictionary which, in this case, is a list.

Thus, you can reference members of that list by appending an index operator to the statement above like so: `color_table["Red"][0]` to reference the first element in that list.

To assign it to a variable, simply use the assignment operator `x = color_table["Red"][0]`.

You can also visit Python's documentation site for information on the differences between dictionaries, lists, etc. in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Use pythonic way:

```
color_table = {"Red":[1,2,3], "Blue":[4,5,6]}
>>> for val in color_table.values():
...   for item in val:
...     print item
... 
4
5
6
1
2
3
```

OR

```
>>> for val in color_table.values():
    ...   for item in val:
    ...     # do something with item
```

if you just want to statically assign value:

```
color_table['Red'][0] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
color_table = {"Red":[1,2,3], "Blue":[4,5,6]}

for key in color_table.keys():
    for i in color_table.get(key):
        print("Key {} Value {}".format(key,i))
```

Here, .keys() is a method which allows to access keys of a dictionary. .get(key) is method by how we can access every key one by one. Then by using nested loop we can access every key and its values one by one remained in a list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.