# Simple question subtracting arrays in Python

Tags: python

How to do a SIMPLE subtraction w/ Python in arrays with 3 variables.

```
a = [[8,8,1] , [6,4,1]]
b = a[0][1] - a [1] [0]
c = a[1:b]
print (c)
```

Is this the answer as it is simply outputting the 2nd array from `a`?

Simply typing out the array according to instruction but not understanding how `a[1:b]=[6,4,1]`?  Is `1` = to the 2nd array of `6,4,1` or is it indicating the 2nd array in `a`?  For the `b` variable is the subtraction just keeping the first line of a = `8,8,1 , 6,4,1` the same so that `[1:b]` = the 2nd index of `a`?

Comment: In Python those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: What are `b` and `c`? Variable names are case-sensitive in Python.

Comment: Maybe you should read about [accessing items in lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449360/access-item-in-a-list-of-lists) and also about (list) slicing.

Comment: You're not subtracting arrays, you're subtracting numbers. The numbers happened to come from lists, but that's irrelevant to how the subtraction works.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
b = a[0][1] – a[1][0]
```

the value of `a[0][1]` is `8`, and `a[1][0]` is `6`, so this is equivalent to

```
b = 8 - 2
```

and sets `b` to `2`.

Then you do

```
c = a[1:b]
```

which is equivalent to

```
c = a[1:2]
```

This is a slice of the list `a` starting from index `1` and ending at index `1`. Since indexes start at `0`, index `1` is the second element, which is `[6,4,1]`. So the result of this is

```
c = [[6,4,1]]
```

See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation/509295) for more details about how list slicing works in Python.

Comment: thank you but how is the 2nd list [6,4,1] = to 1:2 ? I understand 1 = 0 but I am thinking that it would be a[1][:2] to include the entire 2nd list?  I did not know that a[1:2] denotes a 2nd set and then 3 elements?

Comment: @YourTrainingExpert I added a link to a question with lots of answers about list slicing.

Comment: The final result is `[[6,4,1]]` not `[6,4,1]`. There's a difference.

Comment: OKAY now I get this !  Thank you!